# What are the best practices to screen scrape thousands of pages in ruby?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

I am building a ruby script that screen scrape a lot of items getting its product url (over 200k items). Now I have to access each item's page and copy some data.

What are best practices to open over 200k pages faster (in terms of code and server)? Beyond the code, is there any special server that I could lend for a couple hours to run my script?

Any suggestions would be wonderful.
Thanks a lot mates.

Comment: You should ask the website's admin what he recommends. Otherwise you might get blocked from that site for causing too much traffic or too many requests in a short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most crawlers, since most of your time here will be spent waiting on IO, you will want to use a multithreaded or evented IO setup to improve throughput. Server-wise, you just need something that will be able to sustain enough bandwidth to satisfy all your requests without capping out; nothing too special there.

However, your bigger issue here is that you should be very sure that you are respecting the site's `robots.txt` and/or request rate limits and throttling your requests appropriately; a few thousands requests/sec to a server is a great way to get your IP permanently blocked. It's generally considered polite to make absolutely no more than 1 request per second, and you should parse the target site's robots.txt to see what URLs are are permitted to crawl and how quickly you may crawl them.